# Issues resetting git head

Tags: git, git-reset

After working on my project and making a few commits, I decided to push and be done for a bit. However, an error occurred somewhere during the process and the project ended up getting severely messed up, with the majority of my changes being eliminated. I tried to reset the project to the latest commit I made using:

```
git reset --hard b91ca10fdfc96ddd0e2aba09b7861117a6bdc17e
```

I then got the message that the HEAD had been reset to this commit. However, when I open the project my changes have not returned. The project is Xcode written is Swift. Any help is greatly appreciated, I would really like to avoid rewriting a massive amount of code.

Comment: Have you tryed to re-download everthing? Just rename the current folder and clone again from origin.

Comment: My changes didn't push to the origin unfortunately, so no luck there

Comment: Have you tried looking for your commits using git reflog?

Comment: I found my commits locally using git log, and then used the most recent commit (shown above) in attempt to reset it, but no changes were incurred

Answer (score 0):

Since I am not aware of your git project status, here's few thought.

1. Do `git log` and check what is your last commit. Also do `git status` to be sure nothing is in working copy
2. Try `git cat-file commit b91ca10fdfc96ddd0e2aba09b7861117a6bdc17e`. If it errors out it means that the shah isn't available.
3. If step 2 results in a commit then, try `git checkout b91ca10fdfc96ddd0e2aba09b7861117a6bdc17e`. It should switch you to that commit. You can later rename this branch.